# ReskKit Post / Put Response headers

Tags: ios, api, rest, restkit

I am currently building and API that will be consumed by an iOS client using RestKit. For the POST (create) operation, I am returning a standard 202 Accepted status with no content. The objectID is set in the location header as the creation on the API is async.

The issue is that the iOS dev has indicated that RestKit does not allow you to access the header information on the response object. Is it possible to access the response object without using the mapping feature in RestKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestKit returns to you the operation which processed the request / response and from there you can navigate through to get the HTTP processing operation and the response object (which contains the headers).

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be the abstraction that the iOS side had built on top of RestKit

Comment: More specifically, if you have the operation in the block, you can get at the NSHTTPURLResponse by doing operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.  If you want the info in the "Location" header, you can get it at: operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.allHeaderFields[@"Location"]